# How can I change the value in each method?

Tags: ruby

From this code,I want to the last line:`puts computer_number`return 3.

But now it`s 5.

how can I do that?

```
def find_at_risk_square(square, computer_number)
  WIN.each do |n|
    array = []
    n.each do |k|
      array << square[k]
    end
    if array.count("X") == 2
      computer_number = array.index(" ") + 1
    end
  end
end

WIN = [[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9],
       [1, 5, 9],
       [3, 5, 7]].freeze

square = {1=>"X",2=>"X",3=>" ",4=>" ",5=>" ",6=>" "}
computer_number = "5"
find_at_risk_square(square, computer_number)
puts computer_number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* change value in `.each` loop. You **can't** return a value from a method like that.

When you do `computer_number = array.index(" ") + 1` in your method, you're assigning to a method-local variable. This will not affect outside world, be it in `.each` method or not.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is very useful for me.